# How to delete selected item from listbox in wix installer using custom action

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I have following code of custom action which delete's all item from the listbox. But, I need to delete selected item from listbox.

```
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult RemoveListItem(Session session)
    {
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.View View = session.Database.OpenView("DELETE FROM ListBox WHERE ListBox.Property='LIST_ITEM'");
            View.Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass id of the item that you want to delete from listbox. after that put that id on your query.

```
public static ActionResult RemoveListItem(Session session, int Id)
```

Comment: how can i get id in wix and pass it to the custom action ?